# How can I extend RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs7

I'm looking for a way to execute a callback whenever someone calls `subscribe` on an instance of a given class implementing `Observable`.

In the absence of a hook in the RxJS library, in pretty much any other object oriented language, I would:

- inherit the class I want to customize (`ReplaySubject` in this case);
- overwrite the `subscribe` method; and
- execute my callback and then delegate the call to the superclass' `subscribe` method.

Something like this:

```js
export class CallbackReplaySubject<T> extends ReplaySubject<T> {

  subscribe(observer: Partial<Observer<T>>): Unsubscribable {
    this.triggerCallback();
    return super.subscribe(observer);
  }

  private triggerCallback(): void {
    // do something when someone subscribes
  }
}
```

In RxJS v7 using TypeScript I'm getting this error message:

```
Property 'subscribe' in type 'CallbackReplaySubject<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ReplaySubject<T>'.
  Type '(observer: Partial<Observer<T>>) => Unsubscribable' is not assignable to type '{ (observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer<T>> | ((value: T) => void) | undefined): Subscription; (next?: ((value: T) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | ... 1 more ... | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | ... 1 more ... | undefined): Subscription; }'.
    Type 'Unsubscribable' is missing the following properties from type 'Subscription': closed, _parentage, _finalizers, add, and 4 more.
```

The deeper I dig into this, the more I come into contact with "underscored" RxJS methods marked as internal, yelling "KEEP OFF!" at me, preventing any customization whatsoever.

So instead of inheritance, I tried the delegation pattern. Well that won't work either because `Observable` isn't an interface but a class. So I end up entangled with these "underscored" internal methods and members again.

Can anybody show me a way out of this?

Up to and including RxJS v6, I was able to solve this with inheritance, inheriting `ReplaySubject`'s internal `_subscribe` method.

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstand you but it seems like what you are looking for is to pipe the value.  How is this different @netmikey?

Comment: If not i guess what you might want to do is override. An example that might be useful is angular implementation of the EventEmitter 
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/15a825c113701583773fa028259518b63760c3b4/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L40

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand exactly what you want to do, but typically to wrap one observable in another I'd just create a new observable using Observable.create and then you can implement your own observer (or partial) that operates on the observable you are wrapping.  If instead you want to create a "new" object just do it - create an object that implements subscribe. There is no  need for inheritance or an interface. Typescript uses Duck Typing. Provided you implement the correct signature you have an Observable.

Comment: [`Observable<T>.subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7e03aa9823dc97c215d0a5e8d79119c80107537b/packages/rxjs/src/internal/Observable.ts#L695) returns a `Subscription`, why _are_ you using a different return type? You seem to be following [`Subscribable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7e03aa9823dc97c215d0a5e8d79119c80107537b/packages/rxjs/src/internal/types.ts#L90-L92), which _is_ an interface.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you did with delegation, but something like https://tsplay.dev/mqqVQm could work - you implement the narrower `Subscribable` interface _using_ a `ReplaySubject` under the hood.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the end goal?